# Why error handling doesn't work in repl but in VSCode it does? discord.py

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, discord.py, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to handle errors for local commands of my discord bot and I get the following error **discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'MissingRequiredArgument'** this only happens when I execute the code in repl and not in VSCode.I also tried the following

```
commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument
```

```
@youtube.error
async def youtube_error(ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Some text")
@tts.error
async def tts_error(ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Some text")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the complete code, but if I understood well, the problem is that in your file exists a `Command` object called `commands`, so that `MissingRequiredArgument` is interpreted by repl as a Command object attribute, that obviously doesn't exist.
There should be something like this in your code:

```
@Bot.command()
async def commands(ctx, *args):
    ...
```

## Repl vs VS Code

Repl is for beginners/dummies, Visual Studio Code isn't.
The VS Code's interpreter probably understood `commands` wasn't referred to your command, so it doesn't raise any error.

Comment: I solved using the complete extension : `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument` thanks for help